# After using dpkg to install a package, APT-cache policy returns wrong version

Tags: apt, dpkg

I needed to update firefox 51 to firefox 57.0.4 on some ubuntu 16.04 PCs (who had apt-mark hold on for firefox).
Since apt-get policy firefox only allows me to update to the latest version (81.0), I searched for the correct .deb package online and installed it using

```
dpkg -i firefox-mozilla-build_57.0.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

But now apt-cache policy firefox still shows the old version of firefox.
That's posing a problem now, since we use the apt-cache policy output in some scripts to determine the current installed version of firefox.
Is there any way to "sync" the version installed via dpkg back to apt's database?

I also tried purging apt-get's version before using dpkg, but that only results in apt-cache policy saying that "none" version is installed of firefox.

Comment: The package you installed has the package name `firefox-mozilla-build` and it should be visible in `apt-cache policy firefox-mozilla-build`. On the other hand, I would not expect it to be present in the output of `apt-cache policy firefox`, because that is not the package's name.

Comment: It `Provides` firefox, but it is a different package.